# Nextjs Router push array

Tags: next.js, router

I want to make a filtering with url parameters on nextjs.
But can not send array data to url.

Here's my "filter" parameter:

```
{"group":["174","175"],"concept":["9","10"],"target":[],"color":[],"material":[],"order":null,"q":"keyword"}
```

and here's my code:

```
 const url = { pathname: `/shop`,  query: filter }
    const urlAs = { pathname: `/shop` , query: filter }

    router.push(url, urlAs, { shallow: false });
```

I want it to return url like;

```
?group=174,175&concept=9,10
```

but It returns like;

```
?group=174&group=175&concept=9&concept=10
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine, if you want to have a list in url query parameters, e.g. if you want `arr=[1,2,3]` you have to set url like this:

```
?arr=1&arr=2&arr=3
```